# Problema implementacion de dos metodos en programa

Tags: java

Tengo una clase padre llamada User y dos clases hijas que heredan de ella llamadas Organizer y Platform de la siguiente manera.

User

```
package edu.uoc.dpoo;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 *
 * @author Guillermo Rodriguez Barcelo
 */
public class User {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String fullName;

    private Platform platform;

    private List < Message > inBox;
    private List < Message > outBox;

    public User(String username, String password, String fullName) {

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullName = fullName;

        inBox = new ArrayList < Message > ();
        outBox = new ArrayList < Message > ();
    }




    public String getUserName() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullname) {
        this.fullName = fullname;
    }


    public boolean checkPassword(String password) {

        if (password.equals(this.password)) {

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public List < Message > getMessages() {
        return null;
    }
    public Organizer asOrganizer() {
        Organizer ObjetoO = new Organizer(username, password, fullName);
        return ObjetoO;
    }



    public Participant asParticipant() {
        Participant ObjetoP = new Participant(username, password, fullName);
        return ObjetoP;

    }



    public Message sendMessage(String to, String Subject, String message) {
        return null;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        boolean prueba = false;

        if ((o != null) && (o instanceof User)) {
            User p = (User) o;
            if (this.username == null && this.password == null && this.fullName == null) {
                prueba = (p.username == null);
                prueba = (p.password == null);
                prueba = (p.fullName == null);
            } else {
                prueba = this.username.equals(p.username);
                prueba = this.password.equals(p.password);
                prueba = this.fullName.equals(p.fullName);
            }
        }

        return prueba;
    }

    public List < Competition > myCompetitions() {
        return null;
    }


    User(User u1) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Organizer

```
/**
 *
 * @author Oviedin33
 */
public class Organizer extends User {
    private List < Competition > competitions;

    public Organizer(String username, String password, String fullName) {
        super(username, password, fullName);
        competitions = new ArrayList < Competition > ();

    }
    public boolean removeSubmission(Submission submission) {
        return true;

    }
    public boolean sendMessage(Competition competition, String subject, String message) {
        return true;

    }
    public Competition newCompetition(String tittle, float target) {
        return null;

    }
    public void closeCompetition(Competition competition) {

    }

}
```

Participant

```
package edu.uoc.dpoo;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Oviedin33
 */
public class Participant extends User {

    private List < Competition > competitions;
    private List < Submission > submission;



    public Participant(String username, String password, String fullName) {
        super(username, password, fullName);
        competitions = new ArrayList < Competition > ();
        submission = new ArrayList < Submission > ();
    }
    public Submission submitPrediction(Competition competition, float prediction) {
        return null;
    }
    public List < Submission > getSubmissions() {
        return null;
    }

    void asParticipant(Submission aThis) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Debo Implementar los métodos `asOrganizer` y `asParticipant` de la clase `User`,estos métodos deben crear un objeto de la clase específica, e inicializar la clase padre con los datos del objeto `User`. Para realizar esta tarea, se pide implementar el constructor de copia de la clase `User`

Realmente no se como implementar esto,en los dos métodos cree un objeto de la clase `Organizer` y de `Participant` pero no entiendo lo de inicializar la clase padre con los datos del objeto user ni como implementar el constructor de copida de la clase User.

Tengo una clase test en la cual se crea un usuario con un método que pertenece a una clase llamada Platform,realmente no interfiere.

```
   Platform platform = new Platform();
    User u1=platform.registerUser(username1, password1, fullName1);

     Participant p1 = u1.asParticipant();
    assertNotNull(p1);
    assertEquals(u1.getFullName(), p1.getFullName());   
    assertTrue(p1 instanceof Participant);

    // Get a organizer object from user object
    Organizer o1 = u1.asOrganizer();
    assertNotNull(o1);
    assertEquals(u1.getFullName(), o1.getFullName());
    assertTrue(o1 instanceof Organizer);
```

Esta es la primera parte del test,se crea un objeto user y luego basándonos en ese objeto se crea un objeto Organizer y otro participant..

Luego se me pide esto

```
    public void userCopyConstructor() {        
    Platform platform = new Platform();
    User u1=platform.registerUser(username1, password1, fullName1);

    // User is not NULL
    assertNotNull(u1);

    // Get a participant object from user object
    User u2 = new User(u1);        
    assertNotNull(u2);
    assertEquals(u1, u2);        
}
```

Mi duda es como hago para copiar del objeto user todos sus atributos y asi poder crear bien los objetos de Organizer y Participant ya que me piden que sean iguales al objeto User u1 que creo en el método registerUser de Platform

Lo que se me pide esto,Cada usuario puede adoptar distintos roles dependiendo de cómo quiera interactuar con la plataforma:
 Participante: Con el rol de participante, el usuario podrá enviar predicciones a competiciones de otros usuarios que estén abiertas.
 Organizador: Con el rol de organizador, el usuario podrá crear y gestionar competiciones.
Si miráis el diagrama UML, veréis que los roles de han definido como especializaciones de la clase User. Por lo tanto, cambiar de rol implica obtener un objeto de una clase más específica. Para realizar esta tarea necesitarás:
 Implementar los métodos asOrganizer y asParticipant de la clase User, que permiten hacer este cambio de rol.
 Estos métodos deben crear un objeto de la clase específica, e inicializar la clase padre con los datos del objeto User. Para realizar esta tarea, se pide implementar el constructor de copia de la clase User.

Comment: No es muy clara tu pregunta, cuando crees una instancia de User, se debe crear los otros objetos??

Comment: Te comento,en la clase test que tengo para probar que todo es correcto crea en la clase Platform que es una clase asociada a user y que tiene el método registerUser un usuario

Comment: Edito la pregunta para que se entienda mejor,disculpas

Comment: "Mi duda es como hago para copiar del objeto user todos sus atributos y asi poder crear bien los objetos de Organizer y Participant ya que me piden que sean iguales al objeto User u1 que creo en el método registerUser de Platform"  tienes que crear otro objeto user, con los mismos valores que user1?

Comment: Creo que tienes un problema grave de herencia, tienes User y dentro de User quieres crear un objeto hijo? eso no hará que sobreescribas al objeto padre... para mi User debería ser clase abstracta y sus implementaciones participant y organizer, implementando Cloneable  y sobreescribiendo clone... no se puedes explicar mejor que deseas hacer?

Comment: Voy a editar con lo que se me pide pero User no es clase abstracta,eso lo pregunte a la persona que puso la practica y me contesto que no..

Comment: Realmente lo que quiero es que al crear el objeto User con unos atributoscrear un objeto Organizer y Platform que hereden los atributos del primero,no se si me explico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si tengo problemas de lectura pero no comprendo bien lo que quieres...

"Mi duda es como hago para copiar del objeto user todos sus atributos y asi poder crear bien los objetos de Organizer y Participant ya que me piden que sean iguales al objeto User u1"

Si esto es lo que quieres solo haz esto...

```
    Organizer org = u1.asOrganizer();
    Participant part = u1.asParticipant();
```